# Folder Dialog Box in C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to show "Folder Dialog Box" in C#/JavaScript, using which user can select their local system directories and not the server directories.

I have already tried with the below code, but it is retrieving me the server directories.

```
string[] objList = Directory.GetDirectories("D:");
```

Comment: why haven't you use [FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) class?

Comment: @styx: thanks for your reply...
this was a web application.
I tried using FolderBrowserDialog class in my aspx.cs, but it is throwing some rights issues when deployed in IIS

Comment: try and look here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21895/Directory-Browsing-in-ASP-Net-2-0

Comment: @styx: Thanks for your reply.....I already tried this and it is retrieving me the server drive only and not the client system local drives

Comment: Is that we can't have folder dialog box through JavaScript or anything else

Answer (score 1):

Yep.

Drop a folder browser dialog onto your form and show it.

```
folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your reply...
this was a web application.I tried using FolderBrowserDialog class in my aspx.cs, but it is throwing some rights issues when deployed in IIS

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve. What does the user do when they browse to their local machine?

Comment: user will just select the local path and submit, the system will process files available in that path..

Comment: So you want to return a local path to your web server, e.g. "C:\My Folder"?

Comment: yes,  Once I got that path "C:\My Folder" I will retrieve all the files from that path and move it to server share path..

Comment: OK.  But your web server is not going to know anything about the hard drive on the client machine! Remember the site is on the server, not the users machine. You can let the user browse to files, select them and upload them, but you can't send a local path to a server and expect that server to access the path. Returning "C:\My Folder" will make the web site look at its own local "C:\" drive.

Comment: Is that we can't have folder dialog box through JavaScript or anything else

Comment: I would have thought so.